# Form the maximum possible date time in the MM/DD HH:MM format using any eight of twelve given single digits

Tags: python, algorithm, date, datetime

I have written a code for the below problem statement which works fine for most of the inputs. But it doesn't work for input like 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3. The answer should be 11/13 11:11 but it returns 0 (which means it couldn't find a valid date). I understood why this is happening but i could not find a solution for this.

**Problem Description:**

> Arun and his sister Usha are challenging each other with some
> mathematical puzzles. Usha, the cleverer one, has come up with the
> idea of givingArun 12 distinct digits from 0 to 9, and have him form
> the largest date time in 2018 with them. Arun is a little nervous, and
> asks you to help him with a computer program. Usha will give Arun 12
> distinct digits. He needs to create a date time combination in the
> year 2018: the date in the MM/DD form (all four digits must be
> present), and the time in the format HH:MM (all four digits must be
> present). The date may be from 01/01 to 12/31 and the time may be from
> 00:00 to 23:59 (in the 24 hour format). The digits provided may be
> used only once in the answer that Arun gives. If more than one date
> time combination may be formed, Arun needs to give the latest valid
> date time possible in the year 2018.
>
> **Constraints**
>
> Single digits (any of 0-9)
>
> **Input Format**
>
> A line consisting of a sequence of 12 (not necessarily distinct)
> single digits (any of 0-9) separated by commas. The sequence will be
> non-decreasing.
>
> **Output**
>
> The maximum possible valid date time in the year 2018. The output must
> be in the format MM/DD HH:MM If no date time can be constructed, the
> output should be 0
>
> **Explanation**
>
> Example1 :
>
> Input
>
> 0,0,1,2,2,2,3,5,9,9,9,9
>
> Output
>
> 12/30 22:59
>
> Explanation
>
> The 12 digits to be used by Arun are given. The maximum valid date
> time using only the digits given, and with each digit used at most
> once is 12/30 22:59 This is the output.
>
> ---
>
> Example 2
>
> Input
>
> 3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3
>
> Output
>
> 0
>
> Explanation
>
> As no digit less than 3 is present in the input, a valid month cannot
> be formed. Hence no valid Date time can be formed with the input
> digits.

**My Code:**

```
seq_a=list(map(int,input().split(',')))
# print(seq_a)
seq_a.sort(reverse=True)
# print(seq_a)
months=[None,None]
days=[None,None]
hrs=[None,None]
mins=[None,None]
#months
for x in seq_a:
    if x <= 1:
        months[0]=x
        seq_a.remove(x)
        break
if months[0] is not None:
    if months[0]==1:
        for x in seq_a:
            if x <= 2:
                months[1]=x
                seq_a.remove(x)
                break
    else:   
        for x in seq_a:
            if x>0 and x <= 9:
                months[1]=x
                seq_a.remove(x)
                break
# print(seq_a)
# print(months,days,hrs,mins)
#days
if months[1] is not None:
    month=int(str(months[0])+str(months[1]))
    # print(month)
    if month==2:
        for x in seq_a:
            if x <= 2:
                days[0]=x
                seq_a.remove(x)
                break
        if days[0] is not None:
            if days[0]==2:
                for x in seq_a:
                    if x <= 7:
                        days[1]=x
                        seq_a.remove(x)
                        break
            else:
                for x in seq_a:
                    if x <= 9:
                        days[1]=x
                        seq_a.remove(x)
                        break
    elif month<=7:
        if month%2==0:
            for x in seq_a:
                if x <= 3:
                    days[0]=x
                    seq_a.remove(x)
                    break
            if days[0] is not None:
                if days[0]==3:
                    for x in seq_a:
                        if x == 0:
                            days[1]=x
                            seq_a.remove(x)
                            break
                else:
                    for x in seq_a:
                        if x > 0 and x <= 9:
                            days[1]=x
                            seq_a.remove(x)
                            break
        else:
            for x in seq_a:
                if x <= 3:
                    days[0]=x
                    seq_a.remove(x)
                    break
            if days[0] is not None:
                if days[0]==3:
                    for x in seq_a:
                        if x <= 1:
                            days[1]=x
                            seq_a.remove(x)
                            break
                else:
                    for x in seq_a:
                        if x <= 9:
                            days[1]=x
                            seq_a.remove(x)
                            break
    else:
        if month%2==0:
            for x in seq_a:
                if x <= 3:
                    days[0]=x
                    seq_a.remove(x)
                    break
            if days[0] is not None:
                if days[0]==3:
                    for x in seq_a:
                        if x <= 1:
                            days[1]=x
                            seq_a.remove(x)
                            break
                else:
                    for x in seq_a:
                        if x <= 9:
                            days[1]=x
                            seq_a.remove(x)
                            break
        else:
            for x in seq_a:
                if x <= 3:
                    days[0]=x
                    seq_a.remove(x)
                    break
            if days[0] is not None:
                if days[0]==3:
                    for x in seq_a:
                        if x == 0:
                            days[1]=x
                            seq_a.remove(x)
                            break
                else:
                    for x in seq_a:
                        if x <= 9:
                            days[1]=x
                            seq_a.remove(x)
                            break
# print(seq_a)
# print(months,days,hrs,mins,"YOLO")
#hrs
if days[1] is not None:
    for x in seq_a:
        if x <= 2:
            hrs[0]=x
            seq_a.remove(x)
            break
# print(seq_a)
# print(months,days,hrs,mins)
if hrs[0] is not None:
    if hrs[0]==2:
        for x in seq_a:
            if x < 4:
                hrs[1]=x
                seq_a.remove(x)
                break
    else:   
        for x in seq_a:
            if x <= 9:
                hrs[1]=x
                seq_a.remove(x)
                break
# print(seq_a)
# print(months,days,hrs,mins)
#mins
if hrs[1] is not None:
    for x in seq_a:
        if x < 6:
            mins[0]=x
            seq_a.remove(x)
            break
# print(seq_a)
# print(months,days,hrs,mins)
if mins[0] is not None:
    for x in seq_a:
        if x <= 9:
            mins[1]=x
            seq_a.remove(x)
            break
# print(seq_a)
# print(months,days,hrs,mins)
if mins[1] is not None:
    print(str(months[0])+str(months[1])+'/'+str(days[0])+str(days[1])+' '+str(hrs[0])+str(hrs[1])+':'+str(mins[0])+str(mins[1]))
else:
    print(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't backtrack, you get a '3' as the first digit in days leaving only 1's and the 11th month doesn't have a 31th.

So '3' is not allowed as first digit here and you need to redo the first digit in month without the '3' and keep that for the next digit.

Answer (score 1):

***On second thought on re-reading the question I realize you wanted to know why your code doesn't work and not a solution to the problem in general, I apologize. Leaving my code here just in case you need it***

You could use backtracking, brute force doesn't seem all that wrong here though

Consider the below

```
In [129]: import random

In [130]: nums = [random.randint(1,3) for _ in range(0,9)]

In [131]: pnums = [(i,j) for i in range(0,len(nums)) for j in range(0, len(nums)) if i is not j]

In [132]: month = -1

In [133]: m1 = -1

In [134]: m2 = -1

In [135]: len(pnums)
Out[135]: 72        

In [136]: nums
Out[136]: [1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3]

In [137]: month_candidates = ([ (i,j) for (i,j) in pnums if ((nums[i]*10)+nums[j]) < 13 ])

In [138]: month_candidates
Out[138]:                 
[(0, 1),                  
 (0, 3),                  
 (0, 5),                  
 (0, 6),                  
 (1, 0),                  
 (1, 3),                  
 (1, 5),                  
 (1, 6),                  
 (3, 0),                  
 (3, 1),                  
 (3, 5),                  
 (3, 6),                  
 (6, 0),                  
 (6, 1),                  
 (6, 3),                  
 (6, 5)]                  

In [139]: nums
Out[139]: [1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3]

In [140]: for (i,j) in month_candidates:
     ...:     if ((nums[i]*10)+nums[j]) > month:
     ...:         month = ((nums[i]*10)+nums[j])
     ...:         m1 = i                        
     ...:         m2  = j                       
     ...:                                       

In [141]: m1
Out[141]: 0 

In [142]: m2
Out[142]: 5 

In [143]: month
Out[143]: 12   

In [144]: temp = [pnums.remove(p) for p in pnums if (m1 in p) or (m2 in p)] # Save some typing

In [145]: len(nums)
Out[145]: 9        

In [146]: len(pnums)
Out[146]: 50        

In [147]: days = -1

In [148]: d1 = -1

In [149]: d2 = -1

In [150]: day_candidates = ([ (i,j) for (i,j) in pnums if ((nums[i]*10)+nums[j]) < 31 ])

In [151]: for (i,j) in day_candidates:
     ...:     if ((nums[i]*10)+nums[j]) > days:
     ...:         days = ((nums[i]*10)+nums[j])
     ...:         d1 = i                       
     ...:         d2  = j                      
     ...:                                      
     ...:                                      

In [152]: days
Out[152]: 23  

In [153]: temp = [pnums.remove(p) for p in pnums if (d1 in p) or (d2 in p)] # Save some typing

In [154]: len(pnums)
Out[154]: 38        

In [155]: hours = -1

In [156]: h1 = -1

In [157]: h2 = -1

In [158]: hour_candidates = ([ (i,j) for (i,j) in pnums if ((nums[i]*10)+nums[j]) < 24 ])

In [159]: for (i,j) in hour_candidates:
     ...:     if ((nums[i]*10)+nums[j]) > hours:
     ...:         hours = ((nums[i]*10)+nums[j])
     ...:         h1 = i
     ...:         h2  = j
     ...:
     ...:

In [160]: hours
Out[160]: 21

In [161]: temp = [pnums.remove(p) for p in pnums if (h1 in p) or (h2 in p)] # Save some typing

In [162]: len(pnums)
Out[162]: 29

In [163]: mins = -1

In [164]: mi1 = -1

In [165]: mi2 = -1

In [166]: min_candidates = ([ (i,j) for (i,j) in pnums if ((nums[i]*10)+nums[j]) < 60 ])

In [167]: for (i,j) in min_candidates:
     ...:     if ((nums[i]*10)+nums[j]) > mins:
     ...:         mins = ((nums[i]*10)+nums[j])
     ...:         mi1 = i
     ...:         mi2  = j
     ...:
     ...:

In [168]: mins
Out[168]: 33

In [169]: print '{}/{} {}:{}'.format(month, days, hours, mins)
12/23 21:33

In [170]: nums
Out[170]: [1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3]
```

***Assumptions***

1. No robust edge case checking
2. Assuming months have 31 days (fixable by using a map to query months)
3. Did it for ints from 1 to 3 (soln is not vastly different for 0 to 9)

#### Explanation

I'll walk you through upto calculating the best month.

1. First generate all pairs of indices digits using the given list of given integers.
2. Then calculate the max pair of indices that when lookedup in the source array and then converted into a 2 digit integer yield the highest number less than 13
3. Remove the indices from future consideration
4. Repeat the process for the other quantities with the appropriate bounds, (24 for hrs, 30/31 for days etc.)

Comment: do you know why i am getting down voted ? I am clueless.

Comment: I think it is because you have not attempted to run a debugger on your code and try to pinpoint where your algo is going wrong. It would be difficult for SO members to pinpoint the error for you in anything more than a  trivial program.

To improve this question I would first try to debug with a debugger/print stmts  and try to figure out where the logic in your prog breaks and then add those details to the question :)

Comment: Look at [ask] for more helpful tips on asking good questions :)